# Can a country import from russia and export to other countries which are banned by russia?

Tags: sanctions, russia, export, import

Provided russia will ban import and export of products to and from specific countries can a country which is not banned by russia import from russia and export it to other countries?

If not what about derivatives of products? Example if russia bans export of wheat to US or UK can countries like China/India or any other neutral country  import wheat from russia and make derivative products from russian wheat and export to other countries? If not how other countries are going to trace the source?

Answer (score 1):

Question: Is anyone involved in a place where (worst case) Russia could throw them into jail, or (almost worst case) Russia could fine them, and they would be forced to pay the fine, or (still bad case) Russia could stop any further exports to that country?

Russia will have laws, the importing company will have laws, and the country exported to as well. For example, the USA could have laws that make it illegal to import goods that are only available because the exporting country is in breach of contract with another contract (a related law is that it is actually illegal for US citizens by US law to bribe someone in another country. Other countries leave that to the other country).

This would so much depend on the laws of the individual countries, on the actual countries, and the actual laws of each country, and in practice the power of each country that the question cannot be answered in general.

Comment: Gnasher729  I was asking specifically about derivative products like maybe bread which is made from russian wheat how is russia going to stop export of that to US question is regarding implementation of such laws

Comment: Pretending that Russia is a state that upholds some sensible laws: Exports go an a truck, there is paperwork to fill out, the paperwork is checked, and sometimes part of the goods are examined, and if you lied in your paperwork and get called, you are in trouble.